Can a 499 Error be caused by the server?
I am getting a 499 error on a particular api call (specifically only when the browser is Firefox). My research has shown the 499 error is caused by the client severing the connection with the api.
However, in my application my backend is making a series of external api requests and it seems like this is where the 499 error is coming from. In this instance does it make sense that my backend is acting as the client and causing the 499 error since it is making api calls?
Lastly if this is the case why would the browser have anything to do with this?
Here is the error I am seeing in my server logs: 499 api.torsera.com/process_storyclientIP="69.180.xxx.xxx" requestID="893c3004-ca76-4fc4" responseTimeMS=29965 responseBytes=0 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0"

Uhm, in HTTP all status codes are provided by the server to the client. You don't even mention what API.

That's what is interesting the error code is not being provided to the client. It is only being displayed in my backend logs.  My website is located here if you want to see: https://www.torsera.com/.  As far as which api calls are failing, my backend makes a variety of calls to different llms. It doesn't seem like it is the same api that fails every time. I will update my question with the error messaging.

Nginx? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973304/possible-reason-for-nginx-499-error-codes

Right, so what I am wondering is if my server is being considered the client in this instance because I am reaching out to other external apis.

responseTimeMS=29965 seems there is a timeout occurring.

Hi @GregAskew, yes you are correct. Since the 499 error is logging to my server and nothing is being sent to the front end I would suspect the timeout is happening between my backend and one of the external apis it calls.  However, if this is the case why would the timeout be browser dependent?

I don't know why it is dependent on the browser, but I completely expect that it would be implementation dependent. I was only pointing out this is a timeout issue and it wasn't mentioned.

Also: seems like this is where the 499 error is coming from this can easily be confirmed with a packet capture. If no response from the server, 100% this is on the client.

Thanks Greg, I'll raise an issue with Firefox and see if they have any ideas.
